# Firebase Cloud Functions setting environment configuration within a cloud function

Tags: firebase, configuration, google-cloud-functions

I'm using cloud functions that call an external service that uses OAuth2 Security.  Each invocation of my cloud function first, authenticates and gets an access token for the subsequent API call to the external service.

The access token expires in 30 mins, so to avoid token expiration, each invocation I get a new token.

I'd like to use the cloud function scheduler to get the access token and save it to the cloud function config, I can schedule this to happen every 25 mins.  This would avoid each invocation requiring to first get an access token.

It does not look like the cloud function environment config allows programmatic updating of config within a cloud function.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#functions-commands

Anyone solved something similar?

UPDATE: As following further docs, the cloud function needs to be deployed again for the configuration update to occur.  I think the solution to this question is likely a CI cronjob, that gets an access token, updates firebase cloud function configuration and redeploys the cloud functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that trying to update the configuration of the function, or redeploying the function altogether, isn't really the best idea here.  You're probably better off just storing the information in a database or some other shared location, then each function can query that to get a hold of the token and its metadata as needed.  The function can store the token in memory for as long as its known to be valid so that it doesn't have to be fetched for each invocation.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'll store the information somewhere else.  I'll need to make it secure so only the cloud functions internally can access.  And use a cloud function to update the value stored periodically.  Thanks